# nginx forward but change location context

Tags: nginx, proxy, forward

I want to have multiple sites proxied by Nginx.
Either using `site1.someIp`, `site2.someIp` or by `someIp/site1`, `someIp/site2`

When I try to achieve this using the following settings:

```
server{
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        location /first {
                proxy_pass http://localThing:somePort;
        }

        location /second {
                proxy_pass localThing2;
        }
}
```

It results in a `/first` forwarding to `http://localThing:somePort/first` but actually, I only want to forward to `http://localThing:somePort`

Currently, I use multiple servers listening on different ports e.g. `someIp:1111`, `someIP:2222` but that is not a great solution.

- I want to either somehow not forward the matched location
- or use mysite.someIp:somePort (but are not sure how to achieve this)

The answer kindly provided by @jdewald is a great start as the HTML is forwarded but NOT the CSS.

So far I noticed it can be simplified to

```
location /first {
    proxy_pass http://someip:somePort/;
}
```

where adding the last `/` after `somePort/` is important but results in the same problem as the CSS is unreachable. The CSS seems to be unreachable as the application (https://concourse-ci.org/) is serving it at `localIp:somePort/public`. This is not a problem if location is set to `/` but as I want to proxy multiple services in a nice manner using one of the two methods described above and not the mapping to `/` using different ports.

Comment: Nice catch on the simplified version, I'd blanked and forgotten that nginx will just replace the matched location. So is the CSS conceptually under /(first|second|...)/public/blah.css (and within the application as /public/blah.css) or first.mysite.com/public/blah.css? Are you wanting to strip the "/public" part or do you want it reachable from there. What  URL is the HTML serving for the CSS?

Comment: The css is served for example from http://myServer:5555/public/main.css?id=fef6507a177742529af48a161e08a9a4 As far as I understand the thing the css is served from the local service from /public and I want to either serve it from `myNginx/service/`or `service.myNginx` I just want all the stuff delivered, just want the service to work.

Comment: So the HTML and CSS are coming from different places? There's really no reason you can't just setup a location block as /service/ { which passes to /public/. I can edit the answer, but it's essentially what you already have, just for each location block

Comment: Ok I will try this. But why doesn't it work automatically? e.g. it works with a single location if I only match `/` but if I match `/something` multiple locations are required?

Comment: Well your issue is that you have applications on different paths internally, so you have to factor that in. Matching on "/" works if your internal location is also served via "/" and not on a prefix

Comment: But shouldn't a switch board ( proxy) be able to handle such a common problem easily?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the problem again. How would nginx know your internal setup automatically? The location blocks are pretty easy to manage

Comment: Maybe you are right. Thank you very much for all the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just rewrite the URI:

```
location /first {
    rewrite ^/first(.*)$ $1 break;
    proxy_pass http://someip:somePort;
}
```

Alternatively you can have the /first block be a regex and proxy_pass to $1 (using the same regex), e.g.:

```
location ~ ^/first(.*) {
    proxy_pass http://someip:somePort$1;
}
```

Comment: thank you this results in HTML getting loaded but css  not http://myIP/public/main.css?id=fef6507a177742529af48a161e08a9a4 and strangely this **public is inserted**

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @geoHeil? Is /public one of your blocks?

Comment: No I filter for /first but strangely only HTML is loaded. The URL is the URL for some CSS. I noticed thath the /public/ was added. But do not know why.

Comment: Most likely that's coming from your application (whatever is sitting at someip:somePort)

Comment: I am not sure if I do not filter e.g. only go for / it works. I can confirm that it comes from the application but I do not know why it does not work if I sue the rewrite

Comment: I can use 'listen 5555;' to set a different forwarding port - and thus can run 2 applications but this is not a great solution.

Comment: @geoHeil I'm honestly still a bit confused by what problem your'e seeing. Can you update the original question with a request/response cycle for urls that work and those that don't?

Comment: @Jashua I got the same problem if you do rewrite only the first HTTP request with have the `/first`. Css, js etc will try to get them from `/` directory because `/first` is not forwarded anymore and server is listening on location `/first` and not to `/`. My question is here https://serverfault.com/q/1005950/563089